# Show different content in a single container when clicking a product (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a shop with about 100 products, each one with it's own id and description. The description box should show up whenever the user clicks the product. Because the content of this description box has to change depending on which product was clicked(eg, showing a different brand, id, price and photo), my best idea is to create 100 hidden containers (description boxes) and make them show up when the user clicks the product. 
Is there a faster option? (Eg: Creating only 1 description box and change the content inside on click?)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".view").click(function() {
    $("#full-description-box").show();
  });
});
```

```css
.product,
#full-description-box {
  background: orange;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 30%;
  height: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

#full-description-box {
  background: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
  <!-- PRODUCT 1 -->
  <img src="#">
  <div class="short-description">
    <h4>HUBLOT</h4>
    <h4>299 $</h4>
    <h2>DIAMOND WHITE GOLD PLATED</h2>
  </div>
  <a class="view" id="product001" href="#">View full description</a>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <!-- PRODUCT 2 -->
  <img src="#">
  <div class="short-description">
    <h4>ROLEX</h4>
    <h4>499 $</h4>
    <h2>GOLD PLATED</h2>
  </div>
  <a class="view" id="product002" href="#">View full description</a>
</div>
<div id="full-description-box">
  <!-- START DESCRIPTION BOX -->
  <img src="#">
  <h3 id="brand">Brand name:</h3>
  <h4 id="full-name">Model: </h4>
  <h5 id="item-id">ID: </h5>
  <p>Full Description: </p>
  <h4 id="price">Price:</h4>
</div>
<!-- END DESCRIPTION BOX -->
```

Comment: why not have a single container and add the contents to it on runtime using ajax call ? you can use modal dialog and customize the feel and look to be the same as the current popup .

Comment: Why not build the description box using jQuery on hover and remove on not hovering?

Comment: This way you are loading all of the information with the page. This may be fine now but with more products it makes the page slow to load. Look into AJAX which would let you load the product information when you need it.

Comment: I think I am going to try with modal dialog and ajax. I am not building the box in jQuery and show it on hover because I added something else to show up on hover, using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution without changing to much to your existing code.

Note:

1. I removed the `id` attributes as ids should be unique!
2. I added `data-view-id="product002"` to the detail container

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".view").click(function() {  
    // $(this).attr('id') is the id of the clicked .view element   
    $('[data-view-id="'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.product,
.full-description-box {
  background: orange;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 30%;
  height: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

.full-description-box {
  background: red;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
  <!-- PRODUCT 1 -->
  <img src="#">
  <div class="short-description">
    <h4>HUBLOT</h4>
    <h4>299 $</h4>
    <h2>DIAMOND WHITE GOLD PLATED</h2>
  </div>
  <a class="view" id="product001" href="#">View full description</a>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <!-- PRODUCT 2 -->
  <img src="#">
  <div class="short-description">
    <h4>ROLEX</h4>
    <h4>499 $</h4>
    <h2>GOLD PLATED</h2>
  </div>
  <a class="view" id="product002" href="#">View full description</a>
</div>
<div class="full-description-box" data-view-id="product001">
  <!-- START DESCRIPTION BOX -->
  <img src="#">
  <h3 class="brand">Brand name: product001</h3>
  <h4 class="full-name">Model: </h4>
  <h5 class="item-id">ID: </h5>
  <p>Full Description: </p>
  <h4 class="price">Price:</h4>
</div>

<div class="full-description-box" data-view-id="product002">
  <!-- START DESCRIPTION BOX -->
  <img src="#">
  <h3 class="brand">Brand name: product002</h3>
  <h4 class="full-name">Model: </h4>
  <h5 class="item-id">ID: </h5>
  <p>Full Description: </p>
  <h4 class="price">Price:</h4>
</div>
```